# Setting enumerated values based on string representions

Tags: c++, string, enums

I have a config file containing string representations of an enum. There are a lot of different enum values. After loading the config, I need to work out enum values from it string representations. Ignoring macros, the only way I can think of doing this would be to create a hideous lookup function doing a string comparison against every possible value. Something like:

```
typedef enum Fields
{
  FieldFlagNone,
  FieldFlagOperation,
  FieldFlagFormat,
  ...
}


Fields getFieldEnum(string fieldName){
  if( fieldName.compare("FieldFlagNone") == 0 ){
    return FieldFlagNone;
  }else if( fieldName.compare("FieldFlagOperation") == 0 ){
    return FieldFlagOperation;
  }else if( fieldName.compare("FieldFlagFormat") == 0 ){
    return FieldFlagFormat;
  ...
}
```

Is there a faster or more concise way of achieving the desired result?

Comment: [`std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)?

Comment: That would reduce the amount of code a bit, thanks. I'm guessing there's no way of looking up the enum value directly when the string is an exact representation of the enumerated value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::unordered_map<std::string, Fields>`, that will speed up the conversion from linear time to constant time:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Fields> fieldsLookupTable {
    { "FieldFlagNone", FieldFlagNone },
    ...
};
```

To make it more concise you can use some macros:

```
#define LOOKUP_TABLE_ENTRY(x) { #x, x }
```

And then:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Fields> fieldsLookupTable {
    LOOKUP_TABLE_ENTRY(FieldFlagNone),
    LOOKUP_TABLE_ENTRY(FieldFlagOperation),
    ...
};
```

If you want to go really hardcore on eliminating duplication, you can do something like this:

```
#define ENUM_MODE_DEFINE 0
#define ENUM_MODE_LOOKUP 1

#define ENUM_BEGIN(x) \
#if ENUM_MODE == ENUM_MODE_DEFINE \
typedef enum x { \
#else \
#define LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME x ## LookupTable \
std::unordered_map<std::string, x> LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME; \
#endif

#define ENUM_ENTRY(x) \
#if ENUM_MODE == ENUM_MODE_DEFINE \
x, \
#else \
LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME[#x] = x; \
#endif

#define ENUM_END \
#if ENUM_MODE == ENUM_MODE_DEFINE \
} \
#else \
#undef LOOKUP_TABLE_NAME \
#endif
```

And then define your enum like this:

```
#define FIELDS \
ENUM_BEGIN(Fields) \
ENUM_ENTRY(FieldFlagNone) \
ENUM_ENTRY(FieldFlagOperation) \
...
ENUM_END
```

And where previously there was the enum definition, now there will be this:

```
#define ENUM_MODE ENUM_MODE_DEFINE
FIELDS
```

And somewhere else where you had the lookup table, you say this:

```
#define ENUM_MODE ENUM_MODE_LOOKUP
FIELDS
```

Basically the `FIELDS` macro uses the `ENUM_BEGIN`, `ENUM_ENTRY` and `ENUM_END` macros, which generate different code based on the value of `ENUM_MODE`. If you define it to be `ENUM_MODE_DEFINE`, then `FIELDS` will generate the enum definition. If you set it to `ENUM_MODE_LOOKUP`, it'll generate `fieldsLookupTable`. 
This way we only used the enum entry names in `FIELDS`, so if you change something there, the lookup table and the enum definition will change automatically and won't go out of sync.

Comment: Its a good answer .I'm using an unordered_map now, but I don't think I'm allowed to add macros. Unfortunately VS doesn't allow me to initialise the map in that way; had to create an empty one and populate it (you're missing an = in the initialiser btw).

Comment: @UltimateGobblement Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: 2010. Apparently the feature is not available in versions < 2013

Comment: Well, it's still doable without the initializer list. I'll update my answer when I get back from lunch.

Comment: @UltimateGobblement updated my answer to imperatively fill the lookup table